# Highcharts: How to make SVGRenderer labels responsive

Tags: angular, svg, highcharts, bar-chart

I have a chart where I have placed some labels (custom html label elements) inside of my highcharts graph (above each column in my case). The issue is: when I resize the screen I need these to change their x/y position on the screen to stay above the chart, and at a certain point I would need the values to change to be mobile responsive.

Is it possible to properly make these labels responsive so that the labels remain above the columns?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by manually changing the x/y/padding/text attributes of my svgRenderer label. You can effectively change your label entirely using this approach.

I'm in angular and have a listener for screen resizing:

```
this.chart = Highcharts.chart(.....);
// I used a helper method to create the label
this.chart.myLabel = this.labelCreationHelperMethod(this.chart, data);

this.windowEventService.resize$.subscribe(dimensions => {
  if(dimensions.x < 500) { //this would be your charts resize breakpoint
  // here I was using a specific chart series property to tell where to put my x coordinate,
  // you can traverse through the chart object to find a similar number, 
  // or just use a hardcoded number
   this.chart.myLabel.attr({ y: 15, x: this.chart.series[0].points[0].plotX + 20, padding: 8 }); 
  } else {
   this.chart.myLabel.attr({ y: 100, x: this.chart.series[0].points[0].plotX + 50, padding: 15 });
  }
}

//Returns the label object that we keep a reference to in the chart object.
labelCreationHelperMethod() {
     const y = screen.width > 500 ? 100 : 15; 
     const x = screen.width > 500 ? this.chart.series[0].points[0].plotX + 50 : 
        this.chart.series[0].points[0].plotX + 20
     const labelPadding = screen.width > 500 ? 15 : 8;

      // your label
      const label = `<div style="color: blue"...> My Label Stuff</div>`
      return chart.renderer.label(label, x, y, 'callout', offset + chart.plotLeft, chart.plotTop + 80, true)
  .attr({
    fill: '#e8e8e8',
    padding: labelPadding,
    r: 5,
    zIndex: 6
  })
  .add();
 }
```